# Fraction simplification Rules

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility, fractions

I am studying for GRE and One of the practice questions is a division. After converting my Mixed numeral I get $\frac{90}{72}$ now I just have to simplify.

What I understood is that you divide by  Least common multiplier so I

> > $1.)$ Divide $\frac{90}{72}$ by $2$: And I got $\frac{45}{36}$
> >
> > $2.)$ Divide $\frac{45}{36}$ by $3$: And I got $\frac{9}{12}$
> >
> > $3.)$ and so on until I got to 3/4 which is the wrong answer

If in step $1$, I would have divide by $3$

> > $1.)$ Divide $\frac{90}{72}$ by $3$ and I got $\frac{10}{8}$
> >     $2.)$ Divide $\frac{10}{8}$ by $2$ and I got \frac{5}{4} which is the right answer

What is the rule to simplify fractions?

Comment: You divided 45 by 3 and got 9?

Comment: 45 divided by 3 is 15 not 9, that's why this question is even here :)

Comment: Not divided by LCM. But by HCF.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\frac{90}{72}$.Now,$\gcd(90,72)=18$.

So,dividing numerator and denominator by $18$ we get $\frac{5}{4}.$

Comment: OP's method is to divide by the LCD (which he or she refers to as *Least common multiplier* for some reason), not by the GCD. So you essentially haven't answered the question.

Comment: @barakmanos His method is by the least divisor which is essentially the common prime factors of the two terms...multiplying the common LCDs will always give you the GCD....

Comment: Of course, but that's not the problem that he or she is facing.